# Images Height is not working when set programatically

Tags: ios, swift

I set the height for my images programatically. But it's only working properly on iPhone SE. But not for example on iPhone X.

Here's screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Now let's take a look to my code. As you can see I set x and y position for images programatically. Also, height and width.

```
let kint = skrolas.frame.height // Here's my scrollView frame

    vienas.frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: 17, width: screenWidth-42, height: kint) // Here I set my first image programatically. I want height to be the same like my scrollView height.


    let dydis2 = vienas.frame // Here's my first picture frame

    du.frame = CGRect(x: (dydis2.origin.x+(screenWidth-42)+8), y: 17, width: screenWidth-42, height: kint) // Here's my second picture


    let dydis3: CGRect = du.frame
    trys.frame = CGRect(x: (dydis3.origin.x+(screenWidth-42)+8), y: 17, width: screenWidth-42, height: kint) // And thirt picture
```

So as you see my width is working properly. But my height is don't. And I don't get why. As I mentioned in my code I set my images height to be the same like scrollView.

My scrollView looks like this on iPhone XS:
[image]

Here's the link of my project:
[DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3at7xwm8umksgcl/2.zip?dl=0)

```
@IBOutlet weak var skrolas: UIScrollView!
public var screenWidth: CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
}
public var screenHeight: CGFloat {
    return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using `Autolayout`? And where's your code that sets frames is called?

Comment: if you want to show multiple images with scroll feature use collection view to achieve this.

Comment: Are you setting the image view frames in `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: @DonMag Yes, I'm setting in viewDidLoad().

Comment: @DonMag Also, I assigned link to my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue 1: You should be using auto-layout constraints instead of explicitly setting frames.

Issue 2: You are setting the frame sizes in `viewDidLoad()` which is **before** any layout has taken place, so you don't have access to the actual screen width and height.

Issue 3: You have an "Upload another photo" option, so I'm guessing you may eventually want to show *many* photos. Using your approach, you'll quickly run into memory issues.

You should probably look into using a `UICollectionView`. That would give you "auto" horizontal scrolling and will use memory much more efficiently -- you could scroll through many, many images without issue.

First step, though, to see the sizing issue is to move your sizing code from `viewDidLoad()` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and you'll get proper size values.

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviews() was the case. Anyway, I tried to use UICollectionView. To be honest at first I was afraid that it's too complicated but it seems that it's much more easier. Thank you. I will mark this answer as correct. You gave me two solutions. Thank you.